# querydefs run-time error 3265: item not found in this collection

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

In Access 2007 I'm trying to send the results of a query however, I keep receiving the error "Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection." The error is coming up on the line:

```
Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(ReportQueryName)
```

I've checked spelling on the fields and I've tried messing with the Tools>References to make sure that I have the correct library.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub Command202_Click()

Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim ReportQueryName As String

ReportQueryName = "ReportEmail"

Set qry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(ReportQueryName)
strSQL = "SELECT [ID], [title] FROM Cases WHERE ID = " & Me.ID
qry.SQL = strSQL

DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, "ReportEmail", acFormatXLSX, "email@address.com", ..., , False

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the query exists before you run this procedure, or are you trying to create it?

Comment: The query does not exist before this code is run.

Comment: In that case QueryDefs is quite right to report an error! See my answer for how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `QueryDefs` to create a new query - you have to use `CreateQueryDef` instead:

```
Private Sub Command202_Click()

    Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim ReportQueryName As String

    ReportQueryName = "ReportEmail"

    strSQL = "SELECT [ID], [title] FROM Cases WHERE ID = " & Me.ID

    Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(ReportQueryName,strSQL)

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, "ReportEmail", acFormatXLSX, _
    "email@address.com", ..., , False

End Sub
```

Sometimes your new query will not show up in the Access windows straight away.

If you want it to, you can use:

```
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
```

Comment: It says I can't give it an up-vote because I don't have enough cred yet. I'll try to remember to come back when I do.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Comment: @MarkButler you set `qry` and do not use it.

Comment: I get Error 3075, missing operator (syntax error) in query "field=value". I have a string value. Quoting does not help.

Comment: It's been a long time since I was fluent in VBA, but the "Set..." line creates the new query, names it "ReportEmail" and builds it using strSQL.

Comment: So the next line uses it implicitly as it searches for the query called "ReportEmail" and emails it to the recipient